# css transform solving for translateZ

Tags: css, 3d, css-transforms

I am using this example, http://jsfiddle.net/k1m045uu/ (code also posted below) and am having difficult figuring out translateZ when I change the height and width of the container & image.

I have seen a few posts explaining the calculation behind translateZ, but could someones help to show me from the linked to example and **height of 1300px and width of 2000px**.

Any help at all would probably save me from hours of frustration. Hope someone can help me with this.

```js
var elements = $('.face');
var rotates = [0, 72, 144, 216, 288];

function rotate(deg) {
  elements.each(function(index) {
    rotates[index] = rotates[index] + deg;
    $(this).css('transform', 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(' + rotates[index] + 'deg) translateZ(95px)');
  });
}
```

```css
    #Carousel {
      display: block;
      margin: 100px auto 20px auto;
    }
    #Spinner {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 1300px;
      width: 2000px;
    }
    #Carousel .face {
      position: absolute;
      height: 1300px;
      width: 2000px;
      transform-origin: 50% 50% -250px;
      transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    }
    #Carousel img {
      width: 2000px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
    }
    #Spinner .f0 {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(95px);
    }
    #Spinner .f1 {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(72deg) translateZ(95px);
    }
    #Spinner .f2 {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(144deg) translateZ(95px);
    }
    #Spinner .f3 {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(216deg) translateZ(95px);
    }
    #Spinner .f4 {
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(288deg) translateZ(95px);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=# onclick="rotate(-72);">Previous</a>&nbsp;<a href=# onclick="rotate(+72);">Next</a>
<div id="Carousel">
  <div id="Spinner">
    <img class="face f0" src="img/test1.jpg" />
    <img class="face f1" src="img/test2.jpg" />
    <img class="face f2" src="img/test3.jpg" />
    <img class="face f3" src="img/test4.jpg" />
    <img class="face f4" src="img/test5.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what your problem is. Could you clarify what are you intending ?

Comment: Thanks for asking, it is a problem for ie10 or ie11. I refreshed the code above with the dimensions of the container changed to what I need them at. If you look at it, you will see it doesnt rotate right because the translateZ/perspective are not set right. I am trying to figure out how to solve for these two properties.